# If statement doesn't seem to be affecting my code.

Tags: python

```
units = input('Is your data in km/h or m/s: ')
if units == 'km/h' or 'KM/H' or 'Km/h' or 'kM/h' or 'km/H' or 'Km/H' or 'kM/h': 
    initialV = float(input('Enter the initial velocity:')) 
    finalV = float(input('Enter the final velocity: ')) 
    deltaV = (initialV-finalV)
```

I want my code to, if the user inputs m/s for the units, to skip the indented code above, however, it doesn't seem to be happening as when running it, despite me putting m/s in the input, still, runs the above code.

Comment: The `or` doesn't work the way you think it does. You need `units == 'km/h' or units == 'KM/H' or units == `, etc.

Comment: Why not just check if `units.lower() == "km/h"`?

Comment: You should be using `units.lower() == 'km/h'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the whole expression with "or".

```
if units == 'km/h' or units == 'KM/H' or units == 'Km/h' or units == 'kM/h' or units == 'km/H' or units == 'Km/H' or units == 'kM/h':
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated :-)